# how to do trading using ethereum and smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dao

how to build a trading bot that trade automatically on ethereum smart contract .

here is question in detail:

i wanna do trading like buying or selling stocks using smart contract. how to deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer, in my opinion. It would require a dissertation on Smart Contracts, DAOs, HFT and how to design/create software. It's not obvious to me that a trading bot would need even a contract or a DAO or what their roles would be. Many trading bots exist without Smart Contracts.

Comment: @eth: I have narrowed the question by making it "binary," and wonder if can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu Welcome to the community!  As an experienced Stack Exchange user, seems that you should ask your own question because the OP did not like the edit to the question.